# Will sticking two high-coercivity neodymium magnets together of opposite polarity and equal strength demagnetize them?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Say I have two neodymium magnets of equal strength. If I stick them together in a way they dont like, will they lose strength over time (days or years)? Or is a much larger magnetic field needed?

What if they are placed 1-2mm apart? Will the magnetic field be different enough that I dont have to worry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, somewhat surprisingly, is no, the magnets will not lose strength. Please note this is specifically for neodymium magnets which have the property of high coercivity.

From the KJ magnetics FAQ page:

"Will neodymium magnets lose strength if they are held in repelling or attracting positions for a long time?

In most applications, the answer is simply "no". If the magnets will be exposed to higher temperatures while in repelling applications, the answer is "possibly". The exact answer is a bit too complicated for a FAQ answer, and requires specifics about the application."

http://www.kjmagnetics.com/faq.asp#time

Other magnet types, based on hours of searching, do not have this property.

Answer (score 0):

To switch a magnet, a stronger magnetic force needs to be applied to it.  How strong that field needs to be in order to flip the magnet depends on the material.
For example, a N40 NIB (Neodymium Iron Boron) needs a magnetic forces of 1000kA/m.  Most other magnets will flip with less Coercive force/